# Ant exec after end or with daemon delay

Tags: ant

In a ant script, i need to schedule the execution of a batch file after the end of script (or after a time-lapse).
I tried to wrap the exec task into the parallel+daemons tasks after a sleep task but without success...

```
<echo>--- start ---</echo>
    <parallel>
        <daemons>
            <echo>start daemon</echo>
            <sleep seconds="10" />
            <exec dir="Y:\Test" executable="Y:\Test\exec.bat" spawn="true"/>
            <echo>stop daemon</echo>
        </daemons>
    </parallel>
<echo>--- stop ---</echo>
```

There is any way for do this in Ant? Or it's mandatory insert a timeout into script file?

Comment: I do not know of a `<daemons>` tasks container. Are you using an Ant extension not mentioned in your question? Or did you mean the [sequential](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sequential.html) task ?

Comment: @Lolo no 3rd parts extention is used. I found the `<daemons>` task into the Ant's standard documents https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html